# Trigger unable to find Button inside GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a Button and few file upload controls in a template field inside a GridView. The GridView is inside an UpdatePanel and I'm registering the Button with a Postbacktrigger in the GridView_RowDataBound event.

```
protected void OrderGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)  
{  
   Button lb = e.Row.FindControl("MarkAsCompleteButton") as Button;  
   ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(lb);  
}
```

It's throwing an error that "Control lb could not be found for the trigger in the UpdatePanel".

Can anyone suggest how to solve this?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your button can be found in your data rows and not in header row or footer row. Hence you only want to add your button when actual row is a dataRow.

```
protected void OrderGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)  
{  
   if (e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.DataRow) return;

   Button lb = e.Row.FindControl("MarkAsCompleteButton") as Button;  
   ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(lb);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things done incorrectly here.

1. File uploads won't work inside updatepanel. In other words, file uploads won't work asynchronously. Hence you need to create a full postback always.
2. If you really want some button control inside a gridview to create a partial postback, think about putting the GridView RowCommand event itself to be the AsyncTrigger for the updatepanel.

---

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ... OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
            ...
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="GridView1" EventName="RowCommand"/>
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```